# RXJS 6.3.3 Ionic TypeError: Observable.combineLatest is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

Hello I have the problem that somehow I get this error in my Ionic Project:

> rxjs_Observable__.Observable.combineLatest is not a function

im Using this Versions of RxJs:

```
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
```

And the only time I use Observable is like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

**Edit:**

after debugging I can see the Error gets thrown on this line in my html:

```
<div ngxErrors="email" #emailErrors="ngxErrors">
  <div [ngxError]="['email', 'required']" [when]="['touched']" class="errorMessage">It should be a valid email</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long search I found the answer.
I was using [this ngxerrors module](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngx-errors) which works fine with RXJS 5 but not with RXJS 6.

Sadly there is still no fix for it and the [pull request on github](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngx-errors/pull/52) to fix this for RXJS 6 is not accepted.

Maybe there will be a fix someday :)

Comment: Shameless plug: you might want to use ngx-valdemort instead: https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: Hi @Ireiner I have the same issue, how did you fix this ?

Comment: I see that your pull request has been blocked by a test : https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngx-errors/pull/52

Comment: @Louis Ah I forgot to mention that this isnt my pull request :) I resolved this my going back to RXJS 5 sadly for now... Still No fix for RXJS 6

Comment: ok.  I got rid of the error by deleting all my app directory and cloning the remote again....very weird...

Comment: for me a rollback to RXJS 5 did work. But yes very weird. As I can see there is still no fix for RXJS 6. Probably because they changed way to many in RXJS 6. All imports are differend and so on.